# Python TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list for Parkes error grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to run the function below for two lists but got an error as:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

and it's pointing the line:  (5th line in the code below)

> y_line = ((y_1 - y_2) * act + y_2 * x_1 - y_1 * x_2) / (x_1 - x_2)

**Here's my function:**

```
def parkes_error_zone_detailed(act, pred, diabetes_type):
    def above_line(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, strict=False):
        if x_1 == x_2:
            return False

        y_line = ((y_1 - y_2) * act + y_2 * x_1 - y_1 * x_2) / (x_1 - x_2)
        return pred > y_line if strict else pred >= y_line

    def below_line(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, strict=False):
        return not above_line(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, not strict)

    def parkes_type_1(act, pred):
        # Zone E
        if above_line(0, 150, 35, 155) and above_line(35, 155, 50, 550):
            return 7
        # Zone D - left upper
        if (pred > 100 and above_line(25, 100, 50, 125) and
                above_line(50, 125, 80, 215) and above_line(80, 215, 125, 550)):
            return 6
        # Zone D - right lower
        if (act > 250 and below_line(250, 40, 550, 150)):
            return 5
        # Zone C - left upper
        if (pred > 60 and above_line(30, 60, 50, 80) and
                above_line(50, 80, 70, 110) and above_line(70, 110, 260, 550)):
            return 4
        # Zone C - right lower
        if (act > 120 and below_line(120, 30, 260, 130) and below_line(260, 130, 550, 250)):
            return 3
        # Zone B - left upper
        if (pred > 50 and above_line(30, 50, 140, 170) and
                above_line(140, 170, 280, 380) and (act < 280 or above_line(280, 380, 430, 550))):
            return 2
        # Zone B - right lower
        if (act > 50 and below_line(50, 30, 170, 145) and
                below_line(170, 145, 385, 300) and (act < 385 or below_line(385, 300, 550, 450))):
            return 1
        # Zone A
        return 0
```

Comment: What is the type of `act`? If this is a list `(y_1 - y_2) * act` would result in a list and then you try to concatenate `y_2 * x_1 - y_1 * x_2) / (x_1 - x_2)` to this list.

Comment: `act` is `list` type.

Comment: @nicoring what’s wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can implement arithmetic operators such as `+` and `*` on [any object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). In this case `*` repeats the elements in the list and `+` concatenates two lists:

```py
>>> [1] * 4
[1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> [1, 2] + [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So this is the line where the error occurs:

```py
y_line = ((y_1 - y_2) * act + y_2 * x_1 - y_1 * x_2) / (x_1 - x_2)
```

when `act` is a `list`, then this part `(y_1 - y_2) * act` will repeat the list `y_1 - y_2` many times. This part, however, `y_2 * x_1 - y_1 * x_2` evaluates to an integer. So you have `some_list + some_integer`, which does not work because `+` on a list only works if the other operand is a list too.

I assume you want to calculate this expression for every item in `act`, then you could do

```py
y_line = [((y_1 - y_2) * elem + y_2 * x_1 - y_1 * x_2) / (x_1 - x_2) for elem in act]
```

or use [numpy](https://numpy.org/), where arithmetic operators are the same as for numbers, e.g. `*` multiplies every element in the array with the given scalar.